# Управление кэшированными объектами EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть бэк на .net 6 который выполняет множество запросов в БД и часть самых тяжелых кеширует:

```
public class Class1Repository: IClass1Repository
{
   private readonly string _objectName = "Class1";
   private readonly DbContext _context;
   private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
   ...
   public Class1Repository(DbContext context, IMemoryCache memoryCache,...)
   {
      _context = context;
      _memoryCache = memoryCache;
      ...
   }
   private async Task<List<Class1ResponseItem>> GetClass1Async(Guid id)
   {
      if(!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(_objectName, out List<Class1ResponseItem> result))
      {
         result = await _context.....
                 .ToListAsync()
                 .ConfigureAwait(false);

         _memoryCache.Set(_objectName, result,...)
      }
   }
   private async Task<List<Class1ResponseItem>> UpdateClass1Async(List<string> Class1Names)
   {
      //Upadate Class1
      _memoryCache.Remove(_objectName);
      _memoryCache.Remove("Class2");
      _memoryCache.Remove("Class3");
      _memoryCache.Remove("Class4");
      _memoryCache.Remove("Class5");
   }
}
public Class1ResponseItem
{
   public string Class1Name {get; set;}
   public Guid Class1ID {get; set;}
   ...
}
public Class2ResponseItem
{
   public string Class2Name {get; set;}
   public Guid Class2ID {get; set;}
   ...
   public string Class1Name {get; set;}
}
public Class3ResponseItem
{
   public string Class3Name {get; set;}
   public Guid Class3ID {get; set;}
   ...
   public string Class1Name {get; set;}
}  
public Class4ResponseItem
{
   public string Class4Name {get; set;}
   public Guid Class4ID {get; set;}
   ...
   public string Class1Name {get; set;}
}
```

В выше приведённом примере Class2, Class3, Class4 и Class5 содержат поле с названием Class1Name. И при изменении class1Name (это может сделать пользователь) мне нужно удалять кэши которые содержат это поле, в противном случае пользователь может увидеть устаревшие данные. При этом на данный момент я делаю это вручную.

Проблема в том, что кэшируемых объектов 75+ и все зависимости держать в голове проблематично.

Решил этот вопрос с помощью рефлексии.

При стартапе приложения в отдельный класс добавляются все кэшируемые объекты. По всем полям добавленных классов строится граф зависимостей и далее метод remove выполняется через этот вспомогательный класс. В метод отдаётся только название _objectName изменившегося класса. По графу находятся классы которые содержат ссылку на изменившийся объект и удаляют их.

Проблема этого метода в том, что всё зависит от названий переменных. Если название ввести не корректное (вместо Class1Name -> Cls2Nm), то метод перестанет корректно работать. Но мне кажется я изобретаю заново велосипед.

Какие существуют методы для поддержания кэша в актуальном состоянии?

Comment: Вопрос очень интересный, но, думаю, и очень нетривиальный. Кстати, нет ли смысла вам кэшировать объекты где-то на более высоком уровне абстракции, а не на уровне чтения из базы? Или актуальность данных завязана на изменения базы, которые проходят независимо от вашей объектной модели?

Comment: @CrazyElf c этой же базой взаимодействую другие службы(я бы сказал даже, что база в основном на них работает) На счёт кеширования на более высоком уровне абстракции  - интересная идея. Можете пример скинуть или объяснить поподробней?

Comment: Ну, вы же из этих данных что-то уровнем выше делаете, какие-то ещё объекты? Не зная, как у вас всё устроено сложно советовать на самом деле. А вообще нужно сначала понять - что у вас вообще тормозит. Если чтение из базы, то может лучше оттуда и пойти - например, сделать витрину для ваших данных, из которой уже вам и читать по-быстрому то, что вам нужно. А витрину уже на уровне самой базы поддерживать в актуальном состоянии. Короче, вариантов, как этому вопросу подойти, много на самом деле.